# How can I programatically download the vagrant box(es) specified in my Vagrantfile?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have some automatically generated Vagrantfiles and I am trying to script some Vagrant actions.  Specifically, **I want to automate the process of only downloading the boxes specified in a Vagrantfile**, i.e. doing what `vagrant box add` does but without needing to specify the name or URL of the box as an argument.

Assuming I have a folder with a Vagrantfile in it, and a copy of the box has not yet been downloaded:

- `vagrant up` downloads the box specified in the Vagrantfile and starts the VM.  I don't want to start the VM, I only want to download the box.
- `vagrant box update` downloads the box specified in the Vagrantfile, but it refuses to download a box if no versions of that box have been downloaded yet.
- `vagrant box add` does not download the box specified in the Vagrantfile; it requires an argument.  I'm trying to run this in an automated environment where the box names and/or URLs aren't known beforehand.

How can I automatically download the box in my Vagrantfile without doing anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You could automate the 'vagrant up', which would download the box and then launch the virtualbox.

Then also automate

```
vagrant halt
vagrant destroy
```

Leaving you with the downloaded box ready for future 'vagrant up' usage.